# Ghidra - Mach-O failed to load external libraries

Tags: ghidra, libraries, mach-o, macos

I'm trying to follow the steps in the book "The Art of Mac Malware" and disassemble the malicious part (the `patch` binary) of the EvilQuest malware with Ghidra instead of Hopper or IDA. (https://objective-see.com/downloads/malware/EvilQuest.zip (password: infect3d)).

My problem is, that no external system functions like `_strcmp` are loaded. This library function is used in the main function of the binary to analyze to compare the command line arguments. In Hopper and IDA, the function is identified as `_strcmp` without any problems.
Loading it in Ghidra gives the following information:

```
Linking external libraries to patch...
 [libSystem.B.dylib] -> not found
 [CoreFoundation] -> not found
 [CoreGraphics] -> not found
 [Security] -> not found
```

I don't think this is the problem, because if I'm loading another binary, the same message appears, but functions like `_strcmp` are loaded. (But still shown in the `<EXTERNAL>` section of the 'Imports').

Further, after loading the binary in the code browser and analyzing it, the libraries are shown in the 'Imports' section, but there are no functions in there. Even the `<EXTERNAL>` is empty.

Here is an image of the empty libraries on the left and the function call which should be `_strcmp`.
[image: Screenshot of missing function in Ghidra]

Any clue how I can resolve this and get the function names there?

To reconstruct the problem simply download the malware (but be careful, DO NOT EXECUTE IT!), unzip it and load the `patch` binary into Ghidra.

Comment: IDA contains FLIRT signatures for common libraries (and "Lumina" the crowd-sourcing function naming system), not sure if Hopper also contains a library naming technology.